# MAC ID based login

Tags: angular, security, authentication, .net-core

I have a login developed by angular2 as client and dotnet core as backend. 
now i have to restrict the login by specific computer browser. The user should logged in with using that computer only. 
After a long search, i got two options for this one
1. System MAC ID based login (Store the MAC ID into the database and check the login)
2. Certificate-based login (Create one certificate for one user and install it in user system)

Please suggest me the best or generic method for secure login.

Comment: What is the purpose, what do you want to defend against? Do you want to prevent your legit user from using it from another computer? (Because that's not possible.)

Comment: Yes. I want to prevent login from another computer for some users.

Comment: But for what reason, why? Licensing?

Comment: Yes. My client required this type of login. Do you know how to do?